# How to set the value of a form input field without ID using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms, input

How to set the value of a form input field without ID using Javascript?
I can set the ID for the form, but i can't set an id to it's input.

Comment: can you please post code what  you have done so far?

Comment: You need to include examples of what you have.

Comment: The element's `ID` is just one of the many ways of selecting a node. Please have a read about `selectors`.

Comment: Google " javascript how to select html elements". Click on the 5th result.

Answer (score 0):

Use id for your input like this:

`document.getElementById("myID").value = "Hello"`

You must use ID's for your input, because I don't know how many forms you have.

Here you can see the example:
[Input Text Value](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_text_value2)

If you are looking for a specific tag like all your 'form' or 'input' tag, you can do something like this:

`function myFunction() {
    var list = document.getElementsByTagName("UL")[0];
    list.getElementsByTagName("LI")[0].innerHTML = "Milk";
}`

Here is the example link:
[getElementsByTagName example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_element_getelementsbytagname)
For more info:
[getElementsByTagName](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getelementsbytagname.asp)

Comment: I have no id for the input field. I have only one input with unique name.

Comment: You can put id to it.

Comment: If you are looking for based on 'input' tag, here is example: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_element_getelementsbytagname

Comment: i think the best decision is to use document.getelements.byname

Answer (score 0):

You can use query selector to find the input and set its value like below:

```
document.querySelectorAll("input")[1].value = 'MEEEW';
```